# Stuck on resize for cs50. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: c, resize, cs50

While I was able to scale horizontally, the vertical scale alludes me. For smiley, what I'm using as a test subject, in this specific version the code  copies excess pixels after the face is complete and rather than scale it creates a constant colored bar going straight down the image.

Other times it creates seemingly random results, such as duplicating the bottom half of the face multiple times, creating the bars at a different scale or having the bars produced edge downward to the right.

I've tried nesting the loop with `fseek`, making it an individual loop both with and without a duplicate of the code, an if statement `(var < sz (or n) - 1)` along with using `fseek` with `inptr` and `outptr` but while they've given various results none of them have scaled vertically.

```
for (int i = 0, oBiHeight = abs(oBi.biHeight); i < oBiHeight; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < oBi.biWidth; j++)
        {
            // temporary storage
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            // read RGB triple from infile
            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

            // write RGB triple to outfile
            for (int l = 0; l < sz; l++)
            {
                    fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
            }
        }

        // skip over padding, if any
        fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);

        // then add it back (to demonstrate how)
        for (int k = 0; k < outPad; k++)
        {
            fputc(0x00, outptr);
        }
    for (int m = 0; m < sz; m++)
    {
        fseek(inptr, - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)), SEEK_CUR);
        // iterate over pixels in scanline
        for (int j = 0; j < oBi.biWidth; j++)
        {
            // temporary storage
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            // read RGB triple from infile
            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

            // write RGB triple to outfile
            for (int l = 0; l < sz; l++)
            {
                    fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
            }
        }

        // skip over padding, if any
        fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);

        // then add it back (to demonstrate how)
        for (int k = 0; k < outPad; k++)
        {
            fputc(0x00, outptr);
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the output to scale both vertically and horizontally by a scale of `sz` which is input by the User. What am I doing to stop me from achieving those results?

Comment: One problem I see is that you skip the padding going forward, but you don't skip it when rewinding (seeking backward) to duplicate a horizontal line.

Comment: Recommend to first practice good error checking.  Test the return values of all I/O functions `ftread, fwrite, ftell, fseek`.